# What is the instrument used to play Ahsoka's theme when she leaves the Jedi Temple?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, music, ahsoka-tano

During the emotional moment when Ahsoka Tano leaves the Jedi order at the end of season 5 of Star Wars: The Clone Wars, a variety of musical themes play, one of which is her theme, and it plays on an instrument I can't identify. It's at about 1:50 of [this video](https://youtu.be/QE3AMWnfVXM?t=110). There are strings in the background and some kind of rattle thing, but the instrument playing the main theme that sounds like a cross between a cello and an oboe is what I'm asking about. Does anyone know what instrument this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd argue it's a **bass [shakuhachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakuhachi)** (a Japanese flute).

Kiner says that the theme for Ahsoka was written for a shakuhachi:

> That was the first theme I wrote. And I remember writing for that theme
> and I used Japanese flute called a shakuhachi just trying to feel her
> femininity but her strength, there's this light and there's a Darkness
> to her and there's both of that in her theme you know?

https://www.cineconcerts.com/features/2021/kevin-kiner-the-star-wars-legend

This video demonstrating a bass version of the instrument sounds very similar to the piece in OP's question:

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it includes an actual primary source that helps identify the instrument

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a [Mojave Flute](https://youtu.be/HfdFFxUbR1g?t=191). You can see it in the scoring [here](https://musescore.com/user/35224199/scores/6172258) with the (*expressive*) '***Mojave Flute Solo***' kicking in at about the right 1:50 mark.

[image]

There's a very nice example below of a similar instrument playing a similar score.

Comment: I'm still not convinced this is the correct instrument, but it's the closest anyone has been able to get so I will accept the answer unless a better one comes along

Comment: @cat40 - given that it's the one in the licenced musical score, it's hard to see what else it could be.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that score you linked to was done unlicensed by a fan. MuseScore allows anyone to upload and isn't very strict about enforcing intellectual property restrictions.

Comment: agree w/ @cat40 - https://musescore.com/user/35224199 - user does not appear to be affiliated in any way w/ the original production